# How to change the color from an especific road on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, paint

Is there an EASY way to paint some roads with a color (without creating polygons for each road)?

I need to display some roads with a different color.

Comment: some things in life (and programming) just aren't "easy" :)

Comment: that being said, no. Not as far as I'm aware of. To be sure, it doesn't exist outside of a third party. It is possible that there is some third party I don't know about that will do this, but I doubt it. I'd just try polylines

Comment: Is there a way to get the coordenates of road intersections (by name)?

Comment: @Yeah, Geocoder will do that. The address parser is very smart, so you can pass it something like "X street and Y St, yourCity, yourState" as the address, itll geocode it. Note that this is only available in some countries

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt is right, there is no way to do this, however you can overlay a polyline of that color, perhaps extracted from Driving Directions

Answer (score 3):

The only built-in functionality for changing roads is based on whether they're highway roads, arterial roads, or local roads. To change the color based on this, you can use a [Map Style](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) with the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    featureType: "road.highway",
    elementType: "geometry.fill",
    stylers: [
      { color: "#3c5980" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road.arterial",
    elementType: "geometry.fill",
    stylers: [
      { color: "#4cb348" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road.local",
    elementType: "geometry.fill",
    stylers: [
      { color: "#ca19bc" }
    ]
  }
]
```

If you're talking about individual roads, there is no easy or built-in method to do so.